# HTML URL creation using user input

Tags: html, url, hyperlink

I have an URL as [www.google.com](http://www.google.com) at end of URL I need to add Three user input. so final URL will be google.com/a+b+c.

```
    <Html>
    <head>
    <body>
    <label for="ina">Input A:</label><br>
      <input type="text" id="ina" name="ina"><br><br>
    <label for="inb">Input B:</label><br>
      <input type="text" id="inb" name="inb"><br><br>
    <label for="inc">Input C:</label><br>
      <input type="text" id="inc" name="inc"><br><br>
    <a href="https://www.google.com"/input="ina"/input="inb"/input="inc" target="_blank">Submit</a>
    </body>
    </head>
</html>
```

Comment: HTML can't do that. You need to add either a form that submits to a server side program that processes the data and then redirects *or* client-side JS that does more-or-less the same thing inside the browser.

Comment: This isnt how html works... its static. You will need to make use of javascript to capture the user clicking on the link and inject the values from your input fields to create the URL

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use JavaScript:

```js
function submitForm() {
  var a = document.getElementById("ina").value;
  var b = document.getElementById("inb").value;
  var c = document.getElementById("inc").value;
  window.location='https://www.google.com/' + a + "+" + b + "+" + c;
}
```

```html
<label for="ina">Input A:</label><br>
<input type="text" id="ina" name="ina"><br><br>
<label for="inb">Input B:</label><br>
<input type="text" id="inb" name="inb"><br><br>
<label for="inc">Input C:</label><br>
<input type="text" id="inc" name="inc"><br><br>
<button onclick="submitForm()">Submit</button>
```

Or use Window.open to open it in new tab/window:

```js
function submitForm() {
  var a = document.getElementById("ina").value;
  var b = document.getElementById("inb").value;
  var c = document.getElementById("inc").value;
  window.open('https://www.google.com/' + a + "+" + b + "+" + c, "_blank");
}
```

```html
<label for="ina">Input A:</label><br>
<input type="text" id="ina" name="ina"><br><br>
<label for="inb">Input B:</label><br>
<input type="text" id="inb" name="inb"><br><br>
<label for="inc">Input C:</label><br>
<input type="text" id="inc" name="inc"><br><br>
<button onclick="submitForm()">Submit</button>
```

(Snippet will not work in Stack Overflow, because opening new windwos are not allowed in snippets)

Comment: Yes its working. Thank you so much! @metropolisCZ